# How to send encrypted request in python using algorithm rijndael 256 and mode ECB?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

If I am generating request in php using rijndael 256 algorithm and ECB mode then it is working.

Ex of php

```
$enc_request = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $this->_user_key, json_encode($request_params), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
```

My requirement to generate same request in python.

```
from rijndael.cipher.crypt import new
from rijndael.cipher.blockcipher import *
import json
import base64

var = {'controller':'user','action':'check'}
plaintext =json.dumps(var)
print(plaintext)
key='werewrewrewrwerlkewrjewklrwelkrwelkr'
rjn = new(key, MODE_ECB, blocksize=32)
key = rjn.encrypt(plaintext)
print base64.b64encode(key)
```

Key is generating but blocksize is 32. How can we generate using block 256 in python.

Comment: That `blocksize=32` is almost certainly the block size in bytes, so it's 256 bits. A block size of 32 bits for Rijndael is _possible_, but ridiculously tiny. But you should verify that in the docs of the library you're using. You should also check that the key size in the Python version is the same as what your PHP version is using.

Comment: BTW, is there some reason you're using ECB? It's vulnerable to various attacks, even with a 256 bit block. The Wikipedia article on [Block_ciphers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_%28ECB%29) has some information on this.

Comment: Why does this question have the `python-3.x` tag if you're using Python 2?